# Carry compound bow on back

Tags: gear, hiking, safety, bow-hunting

I'm new to hunting. Last time I went, I found myself needing to go up or down relatively steep slopes with a little bit of snow. For that kind of terrain it's nice to have both hands free to catch yourself if you slip, or to allow you to scramble up a particularly steep part on all fours.

For these situations I think it would be useful to carry my compound bow on my back. I experimented with adding a couple straps to my bow, and that allowed me to wear it on my back quite nicely. However the sight presses into my back a little bit and I'm afraid it'll move out of alignment.

How can I safely, inexpensively, carry my bow on my back so both hands are free?

EDIT: I'm looking for solutions that are relatively quick because I'll be doing this several times during the day. So a full-blown backpack that requires me to take the pack off, mess with multiple clips and pockets, etc. is a little overkill. On the other end of the spectrum, it would be nice to have something that allows me to get the bow out, nock an arrow, and shoot in just a few seconds. However I realize that may be unrealistic, so I'm looking for something in between.

Comment: I have never used a bow, but isn't their some kind of carry case you could buy?

Comment: I've looked, but closest thing I can find is a [bow hunting backpack](http://www.cabelas.com/product/Hunting/Hunting-Accessories/Hunting-Bags-Packs|/pc/104791680/c/104734980/sc/104392080/Eberlestock8482-Tailhook-Pack/753428.uts?destination=%2Fcategory%2FHunting-Bags-Packs%2F104392080.uts&WTz_l=Unknown%3Bcat104392080), which is pretty expensive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're in the right area, there will always be hunters selling old gear on Craigslist so they can buy new gear. In my case, I was able to find an [Ebrlestock Slingshot](http://www.midwayusa.com/product/2634221571/eberlestock-slingshot-backpack-polyester) for $50 on Craigslist. There was also a [Tailhook](https://www.eberlestock.com/Tailhook.htm) for $100, and while that was a great deal, it was outside my price range. After a lot of experimentation, I got the Slingshot working pretty well.

If you search Craigslist for something like "bow hunting backpack" or specific backpack names and brands, you can configure [If This Then That](https://ifttt.com/) to [email you when something comes up](https://ifttt.com/recipes/79). This allows you to keep an eye on Craigslist for good deals without having to keep going back to the site every day.

Comment: Ha ha ha ha, love it @Unsung

Comment: Is there a time limit actually? Maybe, I can't remember.